# Mobaxterm logs lines are not coming in complete screen

Tags: logging, ssh, openssh, mobaxterm

[image]

The highlighted part is empty, how can I view the logs in complete screen? I am not able to find any settings to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

- edit session
- SSH
- Advanced SSH settings
- enable: Adapt locales on remote server

That did the trick for me.
Regs.